# Should a method for lazily loading and caching an Object in a HashMap be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

Should this method be synchronized?  I guess I don't understand how (and when) context switches can occur, so I don't know if it's possible for more than one thread to get into the if block inside my method.

```js
public class ServiceLocator {
    private static final Map<Class, Object> applicationServices =
            new HashMap<Class, Object>();

    /**
     * Locates an application scoped service.  The service is lazy loaded and
     * will be cached permanently.
     *
     * @param type The type of service to locate.
     * @return An application scoped service of the specified type.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public synchronized static <T> T getApplicationService(Class<T> type) {
        if(!applicationServices.containsKey(type)) {
            // If this method is NOT synchronized, is it possible for more than
            // one thread to get into this if block?
            T newService = ServiceLoader.create(type);
            applicationServices.put(type, newService);
            return newService;
        }
        return (T) applicationServices.get(type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned you need synchronization to ensure that you don't create multiple instances of service.

You should look at the double checked locking idiom used for initializing singltons to improve performance here.

For example, `getApplicationService` itself does not need to be `synchronized`. In most cases it will find the service in cache and locking is only required when you don't find the element  in the map:

```
public static <T> T getApplicationService(Class<T> type) {
    // applicationServices needs to be a ConcurrentHashMap otherwise 
    // the following containsKey can conflict with the subsequent put
    if(!applicationServices.containsKey(type)) {
        // need to synchronize before modifying the map
        synchronized(applicationServices) {
            // check if another thread created the same service while 
            // we were waiting for the lock
            if(!applicationServices.containsKey(type)) {
                T newService = ServiceLoader.create(type);
                applicationServices.put(type, newService);
            }
        }
    }
    return (T) applicationServices.get(type);
}
```

Comment: All of the answers look correct and I appreciate them.  I've selected this as the correct answer because it is very simple, yet accomplishes what I want.

Comment: Note that `applicationServices` should be a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Otherwise calling first `containsKey` and `put` might occur concurrently, which is not safe with `HashMap` (?)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz thanks, yes that is correct. I will amend my answer. Even with that restriction, do you think this will be better than making the entire method synchronized?

Comment: There is no easy way to tell. It depends on the amount of concurrency and cache misses. Unfortunately the only valid result is: you have to benchmark both approaches.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html) older, but good, article has some useful info on double checked locking.

Comment: @RyanJ thanks for the pointer. I was under the impression the double-checked-locking works fine 1.5 onwards but the editor's note on that article says it is broken. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/157213/18573

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are absolutely right, this method requires synchronization. Technically context switch can occur between any two lines in your code, and even inside (e.g. between reading and storing `i` in `++i`).

Note that using `synchronized` keyword does not mean that the thread won't be interrupted and the context switch will not occur while your thread is in synchronized block. It only means that any other thread that tries to execute the same code in other thread will block, effectively allowing the one owning the lock to continue.

Even using `ConcurrentHashMap` won't help you since safe `putIfAbsent()` method requires already existing value for a given key - and you probably don't want to eagerly create service each time.

However there are some better performing approaches to this quite common problem, e.g. see: [How to implement Self Populating EHcache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648346)

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` is the simpliest way to make it thread-safe, but not the most efficient one.

Without `synchronized` your code would have 2 problems:

- `HashMap` is not thread-safe, it should not be used from multiple threads without synchronization.
- One thread can enter an `if` block when another one (with the same `type`) is already inside it, thus two instances of the same `type` will be created.

So, if solution with `synchronized` doesn't satisfy you, you'll need to solve these two problems by other means. The first problem can be solved by using `ConcurrentHashMap`. The second one is more complex and can be solved by putting `FutureTask`s into map, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488059/synchronization-in-a-hashmap-cache/5488409#5488409).

Answer (score 0):

@Tomasz Nurkiewicz

It's possible to use `putIfAbsent()` to compete for a lock; the first thread gets to create the service; other threads wait to be notified. This way, we don't lock the whole map just for one service, which can get stuck. They even have a weird name for it, google "memoizer". Impls with FutureTask actually have subtle bugs or undesired behaviors in certain cases.

The need for such a utility - compute something on first demand then cache it - is quite strong. A good impl isn't trivial, and average programmers shouldn't bother to reinvent it. Java8 probably will ship something like it. For now people can use Guava's computing map.